# Sudo Command Not Found for Plesk User

Tags: sudo, users, non-root-user

After adding a user to sudoers, it doesn't have access to run sudo.

I'm really stumped as to what the issue is but I am running CentOs 7.9 with Plesk installed.

I have added the main Plesk subscription user to the `wheel` group and uncommented the following line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
wheel   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

I save sudoers, and `su` to the user from root and any command starting with `sudo` just returns:

```
sudo: command not found
```

The $PATH in `sudoers` is as follows:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Although I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin:/root/bin
```

I am trying to get the user in question sudo access so that they can access `crontab` as a cron job needs to run under that specific user (and I'm unable to get it working in the Plesk interface).

Currently, the user just gets `crontab: command not found` - in fact, pretty much all commands are not found (not sure if that is because these ones are all only usable for sudo users).

Can anyone advise as to what the heck I need to do to run sudo for this user? Thanks in advance.

## Edit for @terdon

Running `grep username /etc/passwd` returns the following:

```
username1:x:10000:1004::/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld:/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
username2:x:10000:1004::/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld:/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
```

(It is `username1` that I am wanting to grant sudo access to).

Regarding the `$PATH` queries, I ran that after `su username1` from root user. I have not modified that path, it was just like that anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why would the plesk user need or want sudo? Isn't this a daemon user, a user that will only be used by automated processes? Does this user even have a login shell? Your error is because `sudo` isn't in the user's path, so you can fix it by editing the user's `~/.profile` and adding the PATH there, but I suspect this isn't the best way to do whatever it is you really want to do here. If you tell us what the final objective is, we might be able to find a better way.

Comment: @terdon I need to be able to log into an SSH terminal as the Plesk user (which owns all of the website's files and folders) and be able to execute sudo commands. I might have confused matters by saying Plesk user (I just wanted to advise that this server is running Plesk) - the user is the system user that owns the website's document root.

Comment: What does `echo "$PATH"` output at the command line for the affected user and where is `sudo` installed on the system?

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and show us the details of the user. The sudoers stuff isn't relevant at all. We would need to see the output of `grep plesk /etc/passwd`  (assuming the user is `plesk`) and then see if they have a home directory, a login shell, basic configuration files like `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`. I still don't get why you would need to both log in as this specific user _and_ run sudo though. If `plesk` owns the relevant files, you don't need `sudo`. And if you use `sudo`, you don't need to be the owner of the files. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kusalananda `echo $PATH` returns `/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
` and I assume sudo is installed in the regular place for a CentOs 7 OS...?

Comment: Please [edit] to add the information instead of answering in the comments. What user did you run `echo $PATH` as? Why is `/root/bin` the path? Did you run this as root? The `plesk` user shouldn't have access to `/root`!

Comment: @terdon because I need to create a cron job as the system user because if I add it to the root's crontab, it is creating cache files in the website owned as root and causing the website to break... If I log in to the system user, it does not have access to crontab (`crontab: command not found`) ‍♂️

Comment: @terdon I have edited question to include answers to your questions - let me know if I have missed anything. Thanks.

Comment: What an admin always in each Linux system has to do is to just install sudoers and edit the file via the visudo. Nothing more. To be honest I usually add a group admins, then add admins in sudoers to execute all commands without a password and then add user to a group. Simple as that. No need to even edit a PATH or anything like that. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of this. If the objective is to run a cronjob as this user, all you need to do is add an entry to `/etc/crontab`. This file has an extra field that normal per-user crontabs don't have where you can define the user to run the command:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
0 * * * *   plesk    command_to_be_run
```

That will run `command_to_be_run` every hour, on the hour, by the user `plesk`.

---

Your approach wouldn't work because as a system user, `plesk` doesn't have a proper login shell, as you can see in the `/etc/passwd`, and isn't set up to be used interactively, so there is no `$HOME/.profile` with the correct `PATH` variable etc. As a result, the user's `PATH` doesn't contain the path of the `sudo` executable so it cannot run it. In any case, you can't run cron stuff with `sudo` easily, you would need to set it up to run passwordless but the whole thing isn't needed as explained above.

Finally, your `PATH` as shown in the question isn't the path of the actual `plesk` user, because `su plesk` won't read the user's startup files, you would have needed `su - plesk`. From `man su`:

```
   -, -l, --login
       Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a
       real login:

       •   clears all the environment variables except TERM and variables
           specified by --whitelist-environment

       •   initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER,
           LOGNAME, and PATH

       •   changes to the target user’s home directory

       •   sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a
           login shell
```

Comment: `/etc/crontab` is the root's crontab is it not? I need the system user's `crontab`?

Comment: @zigojacko no, `/etc/crontab` is the system's main crontab and the place where you set commands that need to be run by specific users. Note the `plesk` in the crontab line. Root's crontab, if it exists, would be in `/var/spool/cron/root`. But `/etc/crontab` is the standard way of running cron commands as a specific user.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help with this @terdon - I had already done all this but Plesk broke the cron job so I think it is Plesk causing the issue seeing as their interface can't even support the cron job I am running. But you've helped me with all the information regarding sudo users, permissions, paths and crontab.

Comment: @zigojacko what had you done? Did you _both_ i) use `/etc/crontab` _and_ ii) add a line with the username `plesk` (not Plesk)?

Comment: I had already manually added crontab to the system user's crontab from root like `crontab -u username1 -e`. I appreciate that this result is not what my original question about as I was wanting to specifically get the system user sudo access so the user could access and edit it's own crontab.

Comment: @zigojacko the user never needs `sudo` to access their own crontab. And you can't do this with `crontab -u username1 -e` if the command you want to run in the crontab uses `sudo`. This is _exactly_ what `/etc/crontab` is: a place to have commands that need to be run as a different user.